# iexplore.exe crashes upon login of vmware-server

Tags: vmware-server, internet-explorer

Can some one help resolve, create a process to debug this problem?  The server  meets the minimum hardware requirements of VMWare Server and there is only one VM running on the server.  The administrators guide says that the remote console addin must be downloaded through an automatic prompt which appears when you click on the console within IE..  Firefox and Chrome load the VMWare server portal fine but do not contain the required VM console.

I checked the server logs for VMWare Server: I can post them but nothing stands out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check to verify that the version of IE being used meets the browser requirements (as identified by VMware) and possibly look at any IE add-ons which may be conflicting.